# Load custom polygon as button image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, polygons

I have made a small cross icon using a polygon as following:

```
  <Viewbox Margin="28,-22,-28,22">
        <Polygon
Points="300, 200 325,200 325,250 375,250 375,275 325,275 325,325 300,325 300,275 250,275 250,250 300,250 300,200" Height="513" Width="595">
            <Polygon.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#666666" Opacity="100"/>
            </Polygon.Fill>
            <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="313" CenterY="237" Angle="45" />
            </Polygon.RenderTransform>
        </Polygon>
    </Viewbox>
```

Now I want this polygon to be loaded into my button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that inside `Button.Content`:

```
<Button ...>
    <Viewbox ...>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Don't forget to remove `ViewBox.Margin` (make `Button` big enough) or make it negative.

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The problem is now how do I make the ViewBox wrap the polygon without any extra space around it?

Comment: There are many options: 1) altering points so they start at `(0,0)` 2) scaling 3) negative margin 4) render transform, etc. See edit.